# LaTeX: Is it possible to place the images/tables close to where they are referenced, regardless of where the main blocks of source code are?

Tags: latex

I am wondering is it possible to put the images/tables close to where they are referenced (their corresponding `\ref{images/tables}`), regardless of where the main blocks of source code for these images/tables are? For example, I want to place the table mentioned below in the same page as where `\ref{table:1}` appears, but the code below at the very end of the document, right before `\end{document}`.

```
\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
 \begin{tabular}{||c c c c||} 
 \hline
 Col1 & Col2 & Col2 & Col3 \\ [0.5ex] 
 \hline\hline
 1 & 6 & 87837 & 787 \\ 
 2 & 7 & 78 & 5415 \\
 3 & 545 & 778 & 7507 \\
 4 & 545 & 18744 & 7560 \\
 5 & 88 & 788 & 6344 \\ [1ex] 
 \hline
 \end{tabular}
 \caption{Table to test captions and labels}
 \label{table:1}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally it is best to place the source where the float is referenced the first time. However if you want to collect the sources at a single place (e.g. an external file or the preamble), you could do something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{duckuments}

\newcommand{\taba}{%
\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
 \begin{tabular}{||c c c c||} 
 \hline
 Col1 & Col2 & Col2 & Col3 \\ [0.5ex] 
 \hline\hline
 1 & 6 & 87837 & 787 \\ 
 2 & 7 & 78 & 5415 \\
 3 & 545 & 778 & 7507 \\
 4 & 545 & 18744 & 7560 \\
 5 & 88 & 788 & 6344 \\ [1ex] 
 \hline
 \end{tabular}
 \caption{Table to test captions and labels}
 \label{table:1}
\end{table}
}%

\begin{document}

\duckument

test \ref{table:1}\taba test

\duckument

\end{document}
```

(please don't use `h!` as floating specifier. If anything this will result in suboptimal placement of the floats. Let TeX do what it can best: finding the best possible spot for the floats)